# Rolling 12 from second table

Tags: sql, plsql

I have succeeded to make this work for one row only. But how to make it work for a list of Part No?

```
SELECT 
  T.PART_NO, 
  (SELECT SUM(H.VALUE) FROM 
     (SELECT * FROM HISTORY_TABLE
      WHERE PART_NO='100' 
      ORDER BY A_YEAR DESC , A_MONTH DESC
     ) H
   WHERE ROWNUM <= 12
  )     
FROM MY_TABLE T
WHERE T.PART_NO = '100' 
GROUP BY T.PART_NO
```

Comment: WHERE ROWNUM <= 12 put in main main query instead sub query

Comment: Exactly what logic are you looking for here? "The last 12 records", or "The most recent year of records"? How should missing or different sets of date for different parts be treated? This would be better with a single date column, by the way ... splitting year and month was a bad choice.

Comment: Amit, sorry but do not follow you.

Comment: David, I want the 12 newest records from history table as a sum for each main record.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the analytic function `row_number()` instead of `rownum`.

You are taking the most recent 12 rows from the history table and summing value by part number.  This can be expressed as:

```
select part_no, sum(ht.value), count(*) as NumHistoryRows
from (select ht.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by part_no order by a_year desc, a_month_desc) as seqnum
      from history_table ht
     ) ht
where seqnum <= 12
```

Because there may not be 12 such rows, I've included a count of the number of history rows that match.

I don't see the purpose of `my_table`, unless you have part numbers that are not in the history table.